Is BLAS interface of cvxopt different from standard ones?
According to the official documentation, the description of  BLAS routine tbmv seems no different from the standard routines, for example found in the Intel's MKL Manual.
However, running the following sample code:
from cvxopt import base, blas, lapack, cholmod, misc_solvers
from cvxopt.base import matrix, spmatrix
import numpy as np
x_arr = np.ones((10,10), dtype='float')
w_arr = np.arange(0,10, dtype='float')
x = matrix(x_arr)
w = matrix(w_arr)

for k in range(x.size[1]): # x.size[1] = col size
    blas.tbmv(w, x, n = w.size[0], k = 0, ldA = 1, offsetx = 
        k*x.size[0])


Transforms the matrix x into
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
       [7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7.],
       [8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8.],
       [9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.]])

Seemingly, each loop for k seems to scale the column of matrix x by applying elementwise multiplication of the column and the vector w
What I am wondering is:

Is this an implementation of cvxopt that is different from standard BLAS routine, or am I missing something?
If so, is there a clever way of producing the same results using BLAS routines? (I imagine it's not difficult to loop through columns of matrix and multiplying elementwise WITHOUT using BLAS interface)

